# What is SSH_AUTH_SOCK?

Tags: bash

When I **export** in my terminal I see:

```
declare -x Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.zTF2WfVZJa/Render"
declare -x DISPLAY="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.qhUQdpRp4B/org.macosforge.xquartz:0"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.PowIf5erzI/Listeners"
```

What are these entries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general terms, these lines are user-scoped variables used by applications that you may run. The top two settings appear to be used by the X-Server system. The values may be hard coded, or they may point to a file that contains the information required.

SSH_Auth_Sock is used by [OpenSSH](http://www.openssh.com/) for [passwordless (key based) authentication](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh). It is my supposition that the files pointed to in those profile settings contain temporary data about the services that use them. For instance the listeners file would contain the port numbers that the ssh service is listening for incoming requests connections, which may change based on administrative choices or runtime conditions.

The Display line indicates the current [X-Server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System) virtual display port in use. Notice that the line contains the string [xquartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/). It is my understanding that the Mac windowing system is called [Quartz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartz_%28graphics_layer%29).

I'm not a mac guy, so can't tell you for sure, but the Render line looks to be related to the X servers [Direct Rendering Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_Rendering_Infrastructure)

### Edit:

Upon additional research, I realize I was wrong about the Apple_PubSub_Socket_Render setting. it is related to the Mac RSS/Atom client [PubSub](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pubsub.1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what is the X-Server system and how can I uninstall it?

Comment: you cannot. X is a core part of any linux or BSD derived desktop. it allows you to see bitmap images on a monitor (eg your desktop, windows, and everything else you can see) and operate your userspace hardware. unless you want to use kernel mode command line interfaces exclusively, you cannot avoid X. in 2006 when I started learning Linux, X configuration was always a users first (and often last) challange. I remember trying to configure dual monitors for TV out, on an  nvidia card. talk about trial by fire....